# Display data from SQL according to search options

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to make a search form that will help users filter their results from the database.

How do you sort the results according to the option chosen from the dropdown list?

I mean sort like, if the user selects "Name" from the list, when they hit submit, the table will display all the data but the names will be ordered either ascending or descending (also a user option)

**form (sample of drop down list and radio buttons):**

```
<select name="sort">
    <option value="x">Select a field</option>
    <option value="1">Name</option>
    <option value="2">City</option>
    <option value="3">Occupation</option>
</select>
&nbsp;
ascending<input type="radio" name="sort_order" value="asc">
&nbsp;
descending<input type="radio" name="sort_order" value="desc">
```

**query:**

```
if ($sort !== "x")
$SQL="SELECT * FROM data //what do I add here?//
```

What is the most efficient way of accomplishing this? Any help is appreciated!

Feel free to ask if I'm not being clear as I'm not sure how to word my question well.

EDIT:

I am using an array `$value()` to display the data on a table.

**Sample display:**

```
for ($i=0;$i<$num_results;$i++)
        {
        $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".$row["Name"]."</td>";
        if (in_array("City",$value))
        echo "<td>".$row["City"]."</td>";
           if (in_array("Occupation",$value))
           echo "<td>".$row["Occupation"]."</td>";
```

How do I save the results for my `$sort` and `$sort_order` into `$value()` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$sort = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['sort']);
$sort_order = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['sort_order']);
$SQL="SELECT * FROM data ORDER BY $sort $sort_order";
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll try this one out. One question though, if I'm using an array ($value()) to display the data on the table, how do I save this code's results into the array so that it displays properly?

Comment: It will be exactly the same as if you didn't use an ORDER BY statement. The only difference will be the order of the results returned. The format will be exactlly the same.

Answer (score 1):

```
mysql_query("select * from data order by ".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['sort'])." ".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['sort_order']));
```

Write your sql query like this

Comment: Hi, thank you for your time! I have a question, if I'm using an array ($value()) to display my table, how do I save that code into the array so that it displays properly?

Comment: I used php to make the table. I edited my question to add that info about the table